# Samsung Galaxy S3 Exchange Email Problem when cc'd

Tags: exchange, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S3 and have it set up with my Exchange account and have the setting to download "All" for the email size.  This works fine for most emails.  However, when I am on the "cc" line on an email sent to me, the phone only downloads the first few lines and doesn't even give me an option to retrieve the remainder of the email.  Any advice?

Comment: If stock email app isn't supporting it, I'd recommend to use other email apps from Play Store. Some nice ones are: K9 Mail, Touchdown